# Need to go true While () and foreach()

Tags: asp.net, while-loop, foreach, datatable

Im trying to go true a foreach if a value is less or equal to a number.
I have a while before but it only runs 1 time and then foreach
But need the while to be checked everytime
How can i get that to happen

This is my code that i have tried for now:

```
While (i <= batchSize)
{

foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt1.Rows) 
{
                        var number = dtRow.ItemArray[0];
                        var surname = dtRow.ItemArray[1];
                        var forename = dtRow.ItemArray[2];
                        var emailAddress = dtRow.ItemArray[3];
                        string taxidentifier = (string)dtRow.ItemArray[4];
                        //string taxidentifier = "2211221143";

                        if (Personnummer.Valid(taxidentifier))
                        {

                            body += "{\"itemId\": \"" + number + "\",\"subjectId\": \"" + taxidentifier + "\"},";
                            batch = i++;

                        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` statement condition needs to be checked at every iteration of the `foreach` statement ?

Since the `while` runs only one time, just replace the `while` statement to an `if` one with the same condition at the beginning of the `foreach` :

```
foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt1.Rows) {
    if (i > batchSize)
        break;
    // Do what you have to;
}
```